# Highlight active route in navigation in Meter

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

How can I highlight menu items as active when the user is at the route belonging to this specific item?

I use `iron-router` to routing but it does not support this kind of functionality. Therefore, I have found https://github.com/zimme/meteor-active-route in which I can use `<li class="{{isActiveRoute 'home'}}">...</li>`; however, it seems not to work when I pass parameters to the route, e.g. `{{isActiveRoute 'profile' _id=userId}}`).

Does there exists any good meteor packages to make navigation items active?

Comment: Be cautious. Asking for an external package or resource is off-topic. You should [edit] this part out of your post and rephrase a new question.

Comment: In my previous comment, I noted that you should not ask for an external resource. This includes software libraries, books, and Meteor packages. Asking for a Meteor package will lead to question closure.